# Notifications in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am currently working on a schedule application in Java (Netbeans) and basically, I want to have notifications pop up whenever something is close to being due. I would like them to pop up even when the application is not running. I don't think I'll need a database because all the times and due dates will be specified by the user. Also if it isn't possible to send notifications, is it possible to just automatically open a JFrame on a scheduled time? Thanks!

Comment: *"I would like them to pop up even when the application is not running"* - Some part of your program will need to be running, in order to determine when and how popups are managed

Comment: *"I don't think I'll need a database because all the times and due dates will be specified by the user"* - Then how do you suggest data is persisted when the application is closed?

Comment: Maybe something [like this would achieve your goals](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+quartz&oq=java+qua&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3871j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Saving the data inside a text file during runtime and then taking it out again when the application is reopened. Storing everything locally would be fine.